# integral involving cot coth and e using contour

Tags: calculus, integration, contour-integration

I am thinking it is possible to evaluate this integral using contours, but I got hung up.

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}\sin(ax)\left(\cot(x)+\coth(x)\right)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot \frac{\sinh(\pi a)}{\cosh(\pi a)-\cos(\pi a)}, \;\ a\in \mathbb{N}$

For instance, I broke it up by considering $\displaystyle\frac{e^{-az}e^{iaz}\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}$

and $\displaystyle\frac{e^{-az}e^{iaz}\cosh(z)}{\sinh(z)}$

This means there are infinite poles for the first one at $z=n\pi$ and at $z=\pi n i$

for the second one.  I tried a semi-circle and a rectangle, but got rather hung up.

I got a residue for $z=n\pi$ of $\displaystyle\frac{e^{n a \pi i}}{e^{n\pi a}}$ and a residue for

$\displaystyle n\pi i$ of $\frac{1}{e^{n\pi a i}e^{n\pi a}}$

Since the poles are infinite, there are series to evaluate.

Summing these gave a closed form of $\displaystyle \frac{2e^{\pi a}\cos(\pi a)-2e^{2\pi a}}{2e^{\pi a}\cos(\pi a)-e^{2\pi a}-1}$

Of course, this does not lead to the correct solution.

Another thing to consider is rather 'a' is odd or even.

May I ask what would be the best function to consider or contour to use for this one?.

Thanks

Comment: You realize of course that the integral as stated does not converge unless $a \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes, Ron, I do.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that.  I edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: A solution can be found here, but I thought a contour integration method would be fun and interesting.  http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Bestimmte_Integrale:_Form_R%28x,exp,sin,cot,coth%29     If this wastes your time, feel free to delete it.

Comment: Why does it only converge for $a \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Hey RV.  I am not sure, but I noticed this while playing around with varying values of 'a' with Mathematica.

Comment: @RandomVariable: Because $\cot{x}$ has a pole at $x=n \pi$ when $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @RandomVariable: you have any other bright ideas?

Comment: You can notify a person by using the "@" construct. If you just comment under your own question, @RonGordon for example, will not be notified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We will assume that $a \in \mathbb{N}$, otherwise the integral does not converge.

We use a rectangular contour $C$ with notches cut out as follows:

[image: Rect Contour]

Let us first consider the following integral:

$$\oint_C dz\, e^{-b z} \coth{z}$$

Note that we will be taking $b=(1-i) a$.  By Cauchy's Integral Theorem, this integral is zero because there are no poles inside (or on) $C$.  On the other hand, the contour integral is evaluated along $C$ and may be broken up into six pieces as follows:

$$\int_{\epsilon}^R dx \, e^{-b x} \coth{x} + i \int_0^{\pi} dy \, e^{-b (R+i y)} \, \coth{(R+i y)} + \\ \int_R^{\epsilon} dx \, e^{b (x+i \pi)} \, \coth{(x+i \pi)} + i \epsilon \int_0^{-\pi/2} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \, e^{-b \left (i \pi+ \epsilon e^{i \phi}\right)} \coth{\left (\epsilon e^{i \phi}\right)} + \\ i \int_{\pi-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} dy \, e^{-i b y} \, \coth{i y} + i \epsilon \int_0^{\pi/2} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \, e^{-b \epsilon e^{i \phi}} \, \coth{\left (\epsilon e^{i \phi}\right)}$$

We take the limits as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ and $R \to \infty$.  The second integral vanishes in this limit because $\Re{b} \gt 0$.  Setting this sum of integrals to zero and rearranging a bit, we get

$$\left (1-e^{-i \pi b}\right) \int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-b x} \, \coth{x} = \int_0^{\pi} dy \, e^{-i b y} \, \cot{y} + i \frac{\pi}{2} \left (1+e^{-i \pi b}\right)$$

Note that, in the first integral on the RHS, I used the fact that $\coth{i y} = -i \cot{y}$.

Now we are ready to begin discussing the original integral.  From the above equation, we take imaginary parts; from the fact that $b=(1-i) a$, we may write

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-a x} \, \sin{a x} \, (\coth{x} + \cot{x}) = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1+(-1)^a e^{-\pi a}}{1-(-1)^a e^{-\pi a}} +\\ \int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-a x} \, \sin{a x} \cot{x} - \frac{1}{1-(-1)^a e^{-\pi a}} \int_0^{\pi} dx \, e^{-a x} \, \sin{a x} \cot{x}$$

Remember that $a$ is a positive integer.  I will now prove that the last two terms on the RHS cancel each other out.

Let's take the case where $a=2 n$, i.e., $a$ is even.  Then

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi} dx \, e^{-2 n x} \, \sin{2 n x} \cot{x} &= \int_0^{\pi} dx \, e^{-2 n x} \, \frac{\sin{2 n x}}{\sin{x}} \cos{x} \\ &= \int_0^{\pi} dx \, e^{-2 n x} \, 2 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos{[(2 k+1) x]} \cos{x} \\ &=  \int_0^{\pi} dx \, e^{-2 n x} \, \left[1 + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos{2 k x} + \cos{2 n x}\right] \\ &= \frac{1-e^{-2 \pi}}{2 n} + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \Re{\left [  \int_0^{\pi} dx \, e^{-(2 n-i 2 k) x} \right ]} + \Re{\left [  \int_0^{\pi} dx \, e^{-(2 n-i 2 n) x} \right ]}  \\ &= \frac{1-e^{-2 \pi}}{2 n}+ 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \Re{\left [ \frac{1-e^{-2 n \pi}}{2 n-i 2 k} \right]} + \Re{\left [ \frac{1-e^{-2 n \pi}}{2 n-i 2 n} \right]}\\ &= \frac{1-e^{-2 \pi}}{2 n}+2 \left ( 1-e^{-2 n \pi}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \Re{\left [\frac{2 n+i 2 k}{4 n^2+4 k^2} \right ]} +\left ( 1-e^{-2 n \pi}\right)\Re{\left [\frac{2 n+i 2 n}{4 n^2+4 n^2} \right ]}  \\ &=\left ( 1-e^{-2 n \pi}\right) \left [ \frac{1}{n} +  n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n^2+k^2} \right ]  \end{align}$$

Similarly, one may show that

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-2 n x} \, \sin{2 n x} \cot{x} &= \frac{1}{n} +  n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n^2+k^2}\\ &= \frac{1}{1-e^{-2 n \pi}}\int_0^{\pi} dx \, e^{-2 n x} \, \sin{2 n x} \cot{x}  \end{align}$$

The cancellation occurs when $a$ is even.  One may show that this cancellation also occurs when $a$ is odd, i.e., when $a=2 n-1$ in a similar fashion, using the fact that

$$\frac{\sin{(2 n-1) x}}{\sin{x}} = 1+2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \cos{2 k x}$$

We may then write

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-a x} \, \sin{a x} \, (\coth{x} + \cot{x}) = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1+(-1)^a e^{-\pi a}}{1-(-1)^a e^{-\pi a}}$$

or, in terms of hyperbolic functions, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-a x} \, \sin{a x} \, (\coth{x} + \cot{x}) = \begin{cases} \frac{\pi}{2} \coth{\pi n} & a = 2 n \\ \frac{\pi}{2} \tanh{\left ( n+\frac12\right) \pi} & a = 2 n+1\end{cases}$$

One may easily show that this agrees with the stated result.

Comment: Wow, look at you, Ron. That's great :)

Comment: @Cody: thanks for posting.  This one was a doozy, even though it looked harmless.  It will go on my web site eventually.

Comment: I thought perhaps you would like it.  I actually managed to arrive at bits and pieces of what you have when I considered a rectangular contour, but certainly did not get it all assembled like you just done. Nice work.

Comment: Ron, I was perusing your solution and I have one little piece I am kind of confused about. Is that the residue you have on line 5, on the right side of the equation,  after you rearrange?.   $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}dye^{-iby}\cot(y)+\underbrace{\frac{\pi i}{2}(1+e^{-\pi ib})}_{\text{this here}}$

Comment: @Cody: No residues in the above calculation because there are no poles inside the contour.  Rather, the terms on the RHS are just the values of the integrals over the various pieces of the contour.

Comment: Oh, OK. I am so used to calculating residues I assumed that is what it was.

Comment: I am so sorry, Ron. May I ask, what is that then?.  The $\frac{\pi i}{2}(1+e^{-\pi ib})$ term on the RHS.  I understand the rest of it, but I fail to see where that piece comes from. Sorry for being daft.

Comment: @Cody: I forgot to include a coth term in one of the integrals over $\phi$; this is fixed.  But use the fact that $\coth{y} \sim 1/y$ as $y \to 0$ in the integrals over $\phi$.  BTW you are not being daft, you are asking legit questions about stuff I explain at a million miles per hour.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking those approached 0. Thanks. I will check out what you mention.

Comment: @Cody: They do *not* approach zero!  Very important detail to understand.

Comment: Wow, I see it now, Ron. This one was different. Most contour integrals I have encountered, these terms tend to 0. After we factor out the $1+e^{-b\pi i}$ term, it would appear the integral tends to $\frac{\pi}{2}i$. I see why this one does not.  Interesting indeed.  That is something I may have overlooked.

Comment: @Cody: despite what I said, you can think of them as residues because of the $1/y$ behavior that cancels everything out.  Alternatively, you can imagine going around the poles at $i$ and $o$ the other way so that they are included in $C$; then you would need to use residues.  This way, however, avoids redundant computation.